Is there a correct way to set the icons for my Tauri application?
I have created image by image using Photoshop with the correct size, but is there a more practical way of doing this?

Try $ cargo tauri icon path/to/your/image.
It will generate icons automatically for each platform and place them in the src-tauri/icons/ directory.
You can find more information here.
